# setting column names in wxPython custom table

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a custom wxPython table for storing large grid data.  I based my implementation on the [wiki](https://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPyGridTableBase) and on the wxPython demo.  In order to make it work, I overwrite several of the GridTableBase methods.  I am storing my grid data in a pandas dataframe, so GetColLabel looks like this:

```
class HugeTable(gridlib.GridTableBase):
....

 def GetColLabelValue(self, col):
    """                                                                                               
    Get col label from dataframe                                                                      
    """                                                                            
    if len(self.dataframe):
        return self.dataframe.columns[col]
    return ''
```

I have overwritten SetColLabelValue with the following code:

```
def SetColLabelValue(self, col, value):
    """                                                                                               
    Set col label value in dataframe                                                                  
    """
    if len(self.dataframe):
        col_name = str(self.dataframe.columns[col])
        self.dataframe.rename(columns={col_name: str(value)}, inplace=True)
        return ''
    return ''
```

This code works to change the column name, but it generates this error:

```
TypeError: invalid result from HugeTable.SetColLabelValue()
```

I'm not sure why this error is happening.

I have two questions.  1.  How do I find out what kind of return value is expected?  2.  How do I prevent this error?

Version note: I am using wxPython Phoenix 4.0.0a1 on OS X.

Comment: Documentation is here: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/index.html In your case the docs don't say anything about a return value, so probably it must be `None`

Comment: I tried that, and None creates this error:  `TypeError: invalid result from HugeTable.GetValue(), NoneType cannot be converted to a C/C++ wxString in this context`

Comment: Ah, I was wrong.  That does work!  Thanks

Comment: Could you write it as an answer to your own question and mark it as solved? Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docs are here:  https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/index.html.

Editing SetColLabel to return `None` instead of `''` fixes this problem.